# Creating a login form in Netbeans using SQL Connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a login form in netbeans which obtains the details like the username and password from the mysql database. The program runs but it gives a java.lang.nullpointerexception when i click on the submit button.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author ROSCHLYNN D'SOUZA
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn;   //should not be null
PreparedStatement pat;  //should not be null
ResultSet rs ;//should not be null
    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("CRIME MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Enter Username");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Enter Password");

        jToggleButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jToggleButton1.setText("SUBMIT");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jToggleButton2.setText("EXIT");
        jToggleButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ROSCHLYNN D'SOUZA\\Desktop\\RDBMS Project\\Cover.png")); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        jPasswordField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jToggleButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1))
                .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 94, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 183, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    conn=MysqlConnect.ConnectDB();
       String sql="Select *from login where Username=DBIT and Password=Mumbai";
         try
         {
             pat=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             pat.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
             pat.setString(2,jPasswordField1.getText());
             rs=pat.executeQuery();
             if(rs.next())
             {
                 jLabel1.setText("Welcome to the Crime Management System");
                 Welcome w=new Welcome();
                 w.setVisible(true);
                 show();
             }
             else
             {
                 jLabel1.setText("Invalid login detected!");
             }

         }
         catch(SQLException e)
         {
             jLabel1.setText("Exception Occured");
         }
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        
/**/
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        System.exit(0);
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The errors are

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Login.jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(Login.java:143)
    at Login.access$000(Login.java:17)
    at Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

I just want to know where am i going wrong. And it would be great if someone could explain to me the solution to this problem.

Comment: `conn` seems to be `null` . Apart from that, your query is not correct : `"Select *from login where Username=DBIT and Password=Mumbai"` .

Comment: Check whether this statement indeed returns a Connection object : `conn=MysqlConnect.ConnectDB();`

Comment: @Arnaud The query seems to be correct. It does give me an output when i execute it in the MySQL command line client and shows me the username and password successfully.

Comment: Not sure that `*from` is valid, and your `varchar` values should be inside single-quotes.

Comment: @Arnaud i was able to get the code corrected to an extent where it now shows the java.lang.sqlexception parameter out of range exception